# Using PowerShell to pass all files of a folder as arguments to a command line program

Tags: powershell, variables, get-childitem, csv-import

I'm trying to create a file listing of a folder for a secure file transfer tool. This is what I do:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\files | % {$_.FullName} > c:\temp\list1.csv
$csv = Import-Csv C:\TEMP\list1.csv -Header Path
```

The output holds every file in a new line, but I need it in one line.

Required output

```
"C:\files\Alpha" "C:\files\Beta" "C:\files\Gamma" "C:\files\Delta"
```

Actual output

```
C:\files\Alpha
C:\files\Beta
C:\files\Gamma
C:\files\Delta
```

The csv file is just what came to my mind first. A variable containing the files formatted like mentioned above would be sufficient. Do you have an idea?

**Edit:** Thank you @Matthias R. Jessen and @WaitingForGuacamole, you gave me exactly what I wanted.

```
(Get-ChildItem C:\scripts -File).ForEach({'"{0}"' -f $_.FullName.Replace('"','\"')}) -join " "
```

However, somehow my tool (written in java) is interpreting the output as one file instead of multiple files in a line.
Below the error message:

```
Java : Error: The file 'C:\files\Alpha C:\files\Beta C:\files\Delta C:\files\Gamma' was not found and is excluded from the transfer.
```

I know, that I have to handover the paths differently when using a properties file instead of entering the command manually in PowerShell.
Is there a way on letting the output look like:

```
"C:\\files\Alpha" "C:\\files\Beta" "C:\\files\Gamma" "C:\\files\Delta"
```

Comment: `-join@(Get-ChildItem C:\files -File).ForEach({'"{0}"' -f $_.FullName.Replace('"','\"')})`

Comment: Mathias - I have to say I really love how elegant and compact your Powershell is. The example you provided here does everything except the space between elements. I tweaked it to this: `(Get-ChildItem C:\scripts -File).ForEach({'"{0}"' -f $_.FullName.Replace('"','\"')}) -join " "`, so that I could add the delimiter, and it seems to work

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question according to the new challenge

Comment: Hi @SuperiorOven, welcome to StackOverflow! I'd suggest you also change your title after the recent edit, so that it reflects what you are actually asking for: "Pass all files of a folder as arguments to a command line program".

Answer (score 3):

To pass the file paths of all children of a specific folder to a command line program *as separate arguments*, just pass the results of

```
(Get-ChildItem -File).FullName
```

to the program. Example:

```
$files = (Get-ChildItem C:\MyFolder -File).FullName

# Expected: myprogram.exe -arg1 -arg2 C:\MyFolder\file1.txt C:\MyFolder\file2.txt ...
myprogram.exe -arg1 -arg2 $files
```

Comment: Thank you @Zeemee. This is what I needed!